# Extraneous groupBy in spark DAG

Tags: clojure, apache-spark, flambo

According to the spark DAG vizualization there is a `groupBy` being performed in Stage 1 after the `groupBy` being performed in Stage 0. I only have one `groupBy` in my code and wouldn't expect any of the other transformations I'm doing to result in a `groupBy`.

Here's the code (`clojure` / `flambo`):

```
;; stage 0
(-> (.textFile sc path 8192)
    (f/map (f/fn [msg] (json/parse-string msg true)))
    (f/group-by (f/fn [msg] (:mmsi msg)) 8192)

;; stage 1
    (f/map-values (f/fn [values] (sort-by :timestamp (vec values))))
    (f/flat-map (ft/key-val-fn (f/fn [mmsi messages]
                                 (let [state-map (atom {}) draught-map (atom {})]
                                   (map #(mk-line % state-map draught-map) (vec messages))))))
  (f/map (f/fn [line] (json/generate-string line)))
  (f/save-as-text-file path)))
```

It's clear to me how Stage 0 is the sequence `textFile`, `map`, `groupBy` and Stage 1 is `map-values`, `map-values`, `flat-map`, `map`, `saveAsTextFile`, but where does the `groupBy` in stage 1 come from?

[image]

Since `groupBy` causes a shuffle which is computationally expensive and time-consuming I don't want an extraneous one if it can be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no extraneous groupBy here. `groupBy` is a two-step process. The first step is a local `map` which transforms from `x` to `(f(x), x)`. This is the part which is represented as a `groupBy` block in the Stage 0.

The second step is non-local `groupByKey` which is marked as a `groupBy` block in the Stage 1. Only this part requires shuffling.